# MongoDB shell and server do not match

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect to an mlab database, but when I run the command

```
mongodb://ds119508.mlab.com:19508/myDb -u myUser -p myPass
```

It always prompts this message:

> MongoDB shell version v3.4.0 connecting to:
>   mongodb://ds119508.mlab.com:19508/heroku_xnz5tw94 MongoDB server
>   version: 3.2.11 WARNING: shell and server versions do not match

I'd like to get rid of that. I'm sure I've been installing the `3.4` version by using [this guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: This is because of version you have is different than one mlab on their servers. I'll ignore this warning but if you really want to get rid of it, uninstall your local MongoDB which is version 3.4 and install 3.2.11.

Comment: What are the possible anomalies that could arise from this version inequality? Can somebody know an example ?

Comment: @typelogic I am curious of the same too

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have also encountered with this problem. And it was caused by upgrading mongodb without shutting mongo server down.

Now that you've already have the new version of mongodb (tell from the mongo shell version). You can solve it by just restarting the `mongod` process.

For starting and stopping mongo process, see  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes

Comment: can you tell me the exact command, because i couldn't find it how to restart with specific version?

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

There are probably multiple mongodb versions installed in your machine. I had a similar problem (I uninstalled the old version but not completely) and I followed this link (https://medium.com/@rajanmaharjan/uninstall-mongodb-macos-completely-d2a6d6c163f9) to uninstall all versions of mongodb and reinstall the most updated version and it worked.

Comment: Working solution. Also don't for to run the server again or Windows will not recognize the mongo shell. Here's the instructions: https://hevodata.com/learn/windows-mongodb-shell/#s1