# mongo | WARNING: No implicit session: Logical Sessions are only supported on server versions 3.6 and greater

Tags: mongodb, express, docker-compose

i am trying to run express application on docker. Application depends on mongodb. I wrote a compose file with the contents:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    command: sh -c 'mongo'
    network_mode: "host"

  node:
    container_name: test
    # build: .
    image: node
    working_dir: /code
    volumes: 
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

After running docker-compose i am getting following error:

```
mongo    | MongoDB shell version v4.0.4
mongo    | connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
mongo    | WARNING: No implicit session: Logical Sessions are only supported on server versions 3.6 and greater.
mongo    | Implicit session: dummy session
mongo    | MongoDB server version: 3.2.22
mongo    | WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
mongo    | bye
```

Please help me to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Check if this helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074522/mongodb-shell-and-server-do-not-match

Comment: Hi, akash. Suggestion: Try and format the text in your question to make it more readable.

Comment: Is it possible to change the versions of shell and server?

Comment: Your `mongo` shell version is `4.0.4` and your MongoDB server version is `3.2.22`. The shell warning indicates that [server sessions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/server-sessions/) require a 3.6 or newer server, but if you don't need sessions you can ignore this warning. NOTE: ideally your shell version should match your server version.

Answer (score 0):

Consider explicitly adding image version to your mongo container to make sure that you have a version that corresponds to your client/shell. To this end, in your docker-compose file replace your `image: mongo` line with `image: mongo:4.0` or any other [official Mongo version tag](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) compatible with your shell version 4.0.4.