# How to figure out the compatible shell for a version of MongoDB server?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes-helm, alpine-linux

Runnig commands in my MongoDB shell, I get the warning

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
MongoDB server version: 3.6.12
```

The thing is, I had to use an old version of MongoDB when deploying my MongoDB using [this stable helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb/releases/tag/3.6.12-debian-9-r37) (dating back to Jun 1, 2019) because my client relied on old syntax. On the other hand, I am using an `Alpine` image to create the initial databases and users. That container is using the latest version of MongoDB (I don't specify a version when running `ask add -U mongoDB`). My question is how can I figure out which version of MongoDB will be compatible here with what's present in my DB deployment.

Comment: Did you just upgrade the mongodb? [This can help maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42038030/6082280)

Comment: Hey @ambianBeing, I updated my question to add more details, which also answers your question.